# Use image from ContentPresenter as opacity mask in Windows Phone style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have this button in a Window:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource EllipseButton}">
    <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/user.png" />
</Button>
```

and this is a style

```
<Style x:Key="EllipseButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                 <Grid>
                     ...
                     <ContentPresenter x:Name="content"/>
                     <Border Background="Orange">
                         <Border.OpacityMask>
                             <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ElementName=content, Path=Source"/>
                          </Border.OpacityMask>
                     </Border>                           
                 </Grid>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

so I want to display an any white PNG image I use for my buttons in orange color.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContentPresenter` doesn't have a `Source` property -- its `Content` property would be the `Image` object, which then should contain `Source`...

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ElementName=content, Path=Content.Source"/>
```

If that doesn't work, you could also try binding to `TemplatedParent`:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
    Path=Content.Source}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also found another solution:

in style:

```
<Border Background="Orange">
        <Border.OpacityMask>
             <TemplateBinding Property="Content"></TemplateBinding>
         </Border.OpacityMask>
</Border>
```

and button has ImageBrush as a content:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource EllipseButton}">
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Icons/image.png" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Very nifty solution, I'll remember this one.